# Post Tweet as other user using Twitter API?

Tags: twitter, oauth

I've sorted the OAuth Twitter stuff and currently all my application does is grab Tweets and display them on a web page. After the user has given permission for my application to use their account, is there a way to post a Tweet on their behalf i.e. post AS them?

Answer (score 0):

First point of call would be reading here - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/oauth-echo